# Is there any way to get a csproj dependency to build with Publish

Tags: visual-studio

I have a dotnet SDK-format csproj file that builds a net 6.0 app.

I also have a wixproj that creates an MSI for the app. The files that I want to be in the MSI are the result of doing a **Publish** step on the csproj, rather than a regular **Build** step.

I've configured the wixproj to have the csproj as a ProjectReference.

But when I build the wixproj, the ProjectReference causes a **Build** of the csproj. But I'd like it to do a **Publish** on the csproj.

Is there any way I can build the wixproj so that it will first do a **Publish** on the csproj?